# Slow connection to SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server

After migrating our c# application from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2017, we realized that connection-intensive operations are significantly slower.

I've isolated a code that connects 10000 times to a database and do a simple query there. This code runs about 5 seconds against SQL 2008 (or SQL 2012) but about 25 seconds against SQL 2017.

The code was complied for .NET 4.52 and tested on different machines with different OS, including local executions on SQL Server machines (two different SQL 2017 servers among them). I've tested both *integrated* and *SQL Server* authentication.

Code to reproduce:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection("server=hostname;Trusted_Connection=True;database=dbname"))
    {
        con.Open();
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT 1", con);
        // if I ommit this line, the code runs very fast
        cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

*Updates from comments:*

- *using SQL Server version 14.0.3223 (2017 CU16)*
- *tried various hostnames: `hostname.domain`, `127.0.0.1`, `(local)`*
- *tried to enforce a specific SQL Server protocol (TCP/IP, Named Pipes, Shared Memory)*
- *the first execution after restarting the SQL Service is faster, the further executions are slow the same way*
- *the speed progress is not constant - the code sometimes runs a faster and then slower again (with no other load on the SQL Server)*

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the enabled connection protocols on the sql server instances as well as the priorities (sort order in the list). Are there any other variables like where these instances are on the network or what machines they are hosted on or what the hardware is of those machines. What other software is executing on these machines? What do you observe on the sql server instances if you profile them? Is the response fast (should be duration of near 0 with near 0 reads in Profiler)?

Comment: Any time I see something like this I *immediately* start looking at anti-virus and firewalls.

Comment: Since the connection is not actually physically reopened but pooled, the delay should be exclusively due to processing the "reset connection" packets sent to the server. Per Jacob, I would be more inclined to suspect something interfering with that traffic, than an actual regression in SQL Server 2017. Do you get the same results connecting with `.` (localhost, shared memory)? What about `tcp:127.0.0.1` (localhost, forced TCP)? Did anyone create any server-level logon triggers or other non-standard stuff on the 2017 instance?

Comment: @Igor: Named Pipes disabled, TCP/IP+Shared Membory enabled.

Comment: @JacobH: At least one SQL Server machine is a local server with clean Windows 2019 Server OS, no antivirus installed and even the Windows Firewall turned off.

Comment: Just for completeness, make sure you're using the latest version of SQL Server 2017 (at the time of writing, [RTM CU16](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4508218/cumulative-update-16-for-sql-server-2017).

Comment: Also, though it's not clear from your question if it applies, note any differences in clients as well. "Compiled for" 4.5.2 says nothing about the installed & used version of .NET, other than that it obviously must at least be 4.x for the code to run at all. A major regression in `System.Data.SqlClient` is not that likely either, but there have definitely been quite some changes in authentication lately with the introduction of Azure stuff.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Thanks for your tips. There is an initial version 14.0.2027 (with no CU). I've checked release notes of all CUs but found nothing resembling this issue. However, we will try to apply CU16 and test all again. There is .NET 4.7 installed on client machines (as well as on servers) I'm testing the code on.

Comment: Another "stupid" thing to check: DNS resolution. Using SQL Server authentication with a hard-coded IP address avoids both DNS and Kerberos, possibly allowing you to narrow the issue down further. Also, test what happens if you leave out the `SqlCommand` altogether (testing only connection open/close) and when you properly wrap it in a `using` (which is nicer to garbage collection). FWIW, we use an eclectic mix of SQL Server and .NET versions in our company, including 2017 instances, and I don't recall issues of the sort you're experiencing. That doesn't actually help you, but still.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I agree the problem is somewhere in returning connections to the pool. When testing with different server protocols, an interesting situation occurred: For the "Shared memory only" on server, the first execution of my code after restarting the SQL server was rather fast.

Comment: The same behavior even when connecting to (local) or 127.0.0.1.
According to leaving the `SqlCommand` out (just the `Connection.Open()` remained), I've tested it before and it was very fast. But I'm not able to do any conclusion from that.

Comment: BTW: CU16 applied but no improvements.

Comment: Well, you've certainly got a puzzler on your hands. This isn't a virtual machine possibly subject to variable hardware load, by any chance? That's about the only thing I can still think of. The remainder would require really delving into things, possibly with a debugger on the SQL Server process. You could try comparing [wait stats](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/) between servers, if you can clear them both of any operational load. Beyond this I think Stack Overflow can't really solve this, due to a lack of reproducibility.

Comment: I think is a problem relative to pools, try to read this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51219/max-connection-pool-capped-at-100) have a similar problem.